# AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('google/byt5-base') giving error: OSError: Can't load config and internet connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model, huggingface

```
`tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('google/byt5-base')
```

OSError: Can't load config for 'google/byt5-base'. Make sure that:

- 'google/byt5-base' is a correct model identifier listed on 'https://huggingface.co/models'
- or 'google/byt5-base' is the correct path to a directory containing a config.json file

Edit:

Also was getting error below while upgrading transformer

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('
```

I refereed [this](https://huggingface.co/google/byt5-base) article and checked correct path in the  model repository as well but no luck

Any help highly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. I don't know your transformers version number, you can try to upgrade, I can run this code normally.
2. Check whether the network of your code running environment can access https://huggingface.co, because it needs to download the two files `config.json` and `tokenizer_config.json`
3. If none of the above attempts can solve your problem, you can create a folder and enter and run

```
wget https://huggingface.co/google/byt5-base/resolve/main/config.json
wget https://huggingface.co/google/byt5-base/resolve/main/tokenizer_config.json
```

then modify your code that replace `google/byt5-base` to the path of the floder you create.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll try and let you know. Btw I am running my code on kaggle.

Comment: okay, make sure there isn't a  folder name `google/byt5-base` without `config.json` in `/kaggle/working`. @iamabhaykmr

Comment: It was intenet issue. I had to enable to turn on the the internet  button in kaggle notebook setting. thank you

Comment: My pleasure.  Normally, if the network is not turned on, an error should be reported `ValueError: Connection error, and we cannot find the requested files in the cached path. Please try again or make sure your Internet connection is on.`,  not OSError.

Comment: yeah, I read the log while upgrading the transformer as `WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('

`

Answer (score 1):

It was internet issue. I had to enable to turn on the the internet button in kaggle notebook setting.

[image]